# Not able to print response from HTTP GET request in console.log

Tags: angular

Under Developer tools under Network tab after selecting particular url, getting json data in response body.
But when trying to print it on console .log, result is not showing.

```
let result = this._http.get(url, setheaderAndCredential())  
.toPromise()
.then(res => <MemberInformationDto[]> res.json().data)        
.then(data => { return data; });

console.log('RESULT is',result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let result = this._http.get(url, setheaderAndCredential())  
.toPromise()
.then(res => {
  <MemberInformationDto[]> res.json().data;
  console.log('RESULT is',res.json());
  })        
.then(data => { return data; });
```

you are trying to console when data is not available outside the function, actualy http process is asynchronusly so print within the   `.map` method

Comment: It tried the same but not getting even log 'Result is' string.

Comment: Just check in your network tab whether your request hitting or not properly ?

Comment: @pradeep i getting result Under Developer tools under Network tab

Answer (score 0):

way to call service is

let url = "yourURL";

return this._http.get(url, yourcredentialRequest()).map(res => res.json());

## But when i am accessing this return value via function like below i am able to get url value by inner console.log 'job done get' and not with outer console.log 'hello data' one.

let  hi = this.functionCallToGetReturnValue()

```
   .subscribe(
              data => this.myStringVarable = JSON.stringify(data), 
              error => console.log("Error HTTP GET Service"), 
              () => console.log("Job Done Get !", this.myStringVarable )
             );

    console.log('hello data', this.myStringVarable );
```